# Invert capturing groups in regular expression

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, algorithm, ecmascript-6

Given this (note the capturing groups):

```
/^\w+\[\w+\]\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]$/
```

I want this (note the capturing groups have been inverted):

```
/^(\w+\[\w+\]\[\w+\]\[)\d+(\]\[\w+\]\[)\d+(\]\[\w+\])$/
```

What I have attempted:

```
str = /^\w+\[\w+\]\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]$/.toString()
noncaptured = [];
captured = [];
insideCapture = false;
for (var i = 0, position = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
   if( str.charAt(i) != '(' && insideCapture == false ){
     noncaptured.push([position, str.charAt(i) ] );
   } else {
     if( str.charAt(i) != '(' ){
        position += 1;
     }

     captured.push([position, str.charAt(i) ]);
     insideCapture = true;

     if( str.charAt(i) == ')' ){
       captured.push([position, str.charAt(i)]);
       insideCapture = false;
       position += 1;
     }
   }
}

var arr = captured.concat(insideCapture);
arr.sort(function(){
  if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }   
})
```

I am looking for a clean algorithm. ES6 solution welcome.

Comment: So you essentially want to simplify the code?

Comment: @JackBashford well it is not fully working for one. Second, it is ugly.

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: @cegfault well I grouped the items using a position value. And then joined them together. Now I need to build a new regular expression based on the values.

Comment: Clean solution depends on a few things. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Ry because I will not know the actual real regex in advance. I do know that there will be TWO \d+. But I do not know how many \[\w+\] there will be. Consequently, I will need to replace the TWO \d+ with actual values. So ultimately I was going to do this: str.replace(/INVERTED_REGEX/,"$1"+match[1]+"$2"+(parseInt(match[2])+1)+"$3") )

Comment: @Donato: Okay, that opens up two new directions: 1) what makes you need to invert capturing groups in the first place, and 2) what do you mean “replace the two \d+ with actual values”?

Comment: @Donato: Looking at your edit: is that all you need to do? The equivalent of `str.replace(/INVERTED_REGEX/,"$1"+match[1]+"$2"+(parseInt(match[2])+1)+"$3") )`?

Comment: @Ry the first \d+ is an id of a record I need to preserve and the second is a counter that I need to increment by 1. Maybe there is another solution. But this is the solution I thought of. the \w+ in the regex can change possibly. But the record id and the increment will always be present. And to answer your question, yes that's what ultimately I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there won't be nested parentheses, as in the example, I'd slice out the parts of the string between the leading `/^` and the trailing `$/`, then use a regular expression to capture non-parentheses characters, and replace with that group surrounded by parentheses. Also, after the non-parentheses characters, optionally match `(`s, followed by non-parentheses characters, followed by `)`, and if that group matches, replace with just that group (without parentheses):

```
([^(]+)(?:\(([^)]+)\))?
```

Replace with

```
($1)$2
```

https://regex101.com/r/gLrHsH/1

```js
const str = /^\w+\[\w+\]\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]$/.toString();
const sliced = str.slice(2, str.length - 2);
const output = '/^' + sliced.replace(/([^(]+)(?:\(([^)]+)\))?/g, '($1)$2') + '$/';
console.log(output);
```

```
([^(]+)(?:\(([^)]+)\))?
```

means:

- `([^(]+)` - Non-`(` characters
- `(?:\(([^)]+)\))?` Optional non-capturing group containing:

  - `\(` - Leading `(`
  - `([^)]+)` - Non-`)` characters, captured in a group
  - `\)` - Trailing `)`

Answer (score 1):

Even if I'm not `100%` sure the next will work on all the cases you may need, this can be an alternative approach: *Reverse all parentheses, and add parentheses after `^` and before `$`*

```js
const str1 = /^\w+\[\w+\]\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]$/.toString();
const str2 = /^\w+(\[\w+\])\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]\[\w+\]$/.toString();
const str3 = /^(\w+\[\w+\]\[\w+\]\[\d+\]\[\w+\]\[\d+\]\[\w+\])$/.toString();
const str4 = /^\w+\[\w+\]\[\w+\]\[\d+\]\[\w+\]\[\d+\]\[\w+\]$/.toString();

const replaceMap = {"(": ")", ")": "(", "^": "^(", "$": ")$"};

const reverse = (str) =>
{
    return str.replace(/[(,),^, $]/g, function(match)
    {
        return replaceMap[match];
    });
}

console.log(reverse(str1));
console.log(reverse(str2));
console.log(reverse(str3));
console.log(reverse(str4));
```